# Does the following complex valued sequence converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider $z_n=(-1)^n+\frac{i}{n+1}$, the back of the book says it diverges and here's my attempt at it. Observe that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{i}{n+1}=0$. Now if $z_n$ is a cauchy sequence then $\lim_{n\to\infty} |(-1)^n+\frac{i}{n+1}-((-1)^{n+1}+\frac{i}{n+2})|=|(-1)^n+(-1)^n|=2$ Thus it diverges since it does not satisfy the cauchy criterion

Answer (score 1):

A standard trick is to look at the "odd" and "even" subsequences like $z_{2n}$ and $z_{2n+1}$. These subsequences converge to different values: $1,-1$ respectively. Thus $z_n$ diverges.